# 2nd JQuery Code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have two codes, the second one does not works if first one is added, im not sure where the issue is and how to fix, following are the codes in using in footer of page:

Code 1:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var names = ["input.name","input.first_name","input.last_name","input.email","input.address","input.city","input.state","input.zip","input.phone","input.country"];
    $.each(names,function (index, item) {
        var regex = new RegExp("\\{\\{"+item+"\\}\\}","g");
        var currVal = localStorage.getItem("garlic:"+document.location.host+"*>"+item);
        $("body:contains('{{"+item+"}}')").each(function() {
            var replace_text = (currVal != null) ? currVal : "";
            var replaced = $(this).html().replace(regex, replace_text);
            $(this).html(replaced);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Code 2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#agreeCheckbox').click(function(){
        $('#tmp_button-70655').toggle();
        $('#disablebtn').toggle();

});


$('#agreeCheckboxtwo').click(function(){
        $('#button-99411-155-131-111').toggle();
        $('#disablebtntwo').toggle();

});
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean “does not work”? What did you expect to happen, what did happen, and what errors/warnings (if any) did you receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried deleting one of "ready"?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    var names = ["input.name","input.first_name","input.last_name","input.email","input.address","input.city","input.state","input.zip","input.phone","input.country"];
    $.each(names, function (index, item) 
    {
        var regex = new RegExp("\\{\\{"+item+"\\}\\}","g");
        var currVal = localStorage.getItem("garlic:"+document.location.host+"*>"+item);
        $("body:contains('{{"+item+"}}')").each(function() 
        {
            var replace_text = (currVal != null) ? currVal : "";
            var replaced = $(this).html().replace(regex, replace_text);
            $(this).html(replaced);
        });
    });

    $('#agreeCheckbox').click(function()
    {
        $('#tmp_button-70655').toggle();
        $('#disablebtn').toggle();

    });

    $('#agreeCheckboxtwo').click(function()
    {
            $('#button-99411-155-131-111').toggle();
            $('#disablebtntwo').toggle();
    });
});
```